# How to add values to Map<string, Set<string>> in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I have a map of type Map> , I need to add values to the Set multiple times :

```
Fields = new Map<string, Set<string>>();

 this.array1.forEach(s => this.Fields.set(`${s.id}`, Utils1.otherFields(s)));
 this.array2.forEach(s => this.Fields.set(`${s.id}`, Utils2.otherFields2(s)));
```

now the loop does the job perfectly , but when I return the Map , it only has the last values set in it , which is in this case values from otherFields2.

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: That's because you're overwriting the Set with new data from `Utils1.otherFields(s)` or `Utils2.otherFields(s)` at every iteration. You will need to merge the sets returned in the map, instead of reassigning/overwriting them.

Comment: thank you @Terry , any idea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have a lot of built-in support for manipulating `Map`s and `Set`s, so you'll have to write this yourself.  Here's a possible way to do this.

First, let's introduce the `Map` utility function `computeIfAbsent()`, (inspired by a [Java `Map` method of the same name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function))) which takes a map and a key, and a callback function to compute a default value for that key.  It behaves sort of like a `map.get(key)` which is guaranteed to return a result.  If the map has a value for that key, you get it.  Otherwise, the callback is called to make a value, and that value is put into the map before it's returned to you:

```
function computeIfAbsent<K, V>(map: Map<K, V>, key: K, mappingFunction: (key: K) => V): V {
    let val = map.get(key);
    if (typeof val === "undefined") {
        val = mappingFunction(key);
        map.set(key, val);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Then we introduce the `Set` utility function `addAll()`, (inspired by a [Java `Set` method of the same name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))) which takes a set and a collection of values, and adds all the values from the collection into the set:

```
function addAll<V>(s: Set<V>, other: Iterable<V>) {
    for (const o of other) s.add(o);
}
```

Armed with both of those, your code should be changed to something like this:

```
    this.array1.forEach(s => addAll(
        computeIfAbsent(this.Fields, `${s.id}`, () => new Set()),
        Utils1.otherFields(s)
    ));
    this.array2.forEach(s => addAll(
        computeIfAbsent(this.Fields, `${s.id}`, () => new Set()),
        Utils2.otherFields2(s)
    ));
```

The idea is that for each element `s` in the array, you get the `Set<string>` corresponding to the `s.id` key in the `Fields` map, or create a new empty one if it isn't there.  Then, to this set you add all the values from your `Utils` method.  This should have the effect of merging instead of overwriting.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EwAtQDmyA3gFDIXLAAmAXMgM5hSEDcpAvqQuiE8gFUwwADYMAjMgC8JcpXR5oAMWAQR1BgAoAHvQzY8hAJSzKZ5FBwBXKCGQgIAdzQ5NAbW0A6GsgDUyACIAQgCAGmQvH38AgH4wiO9qP0DPAIBdI3YzLi4ePjBBYTEAJmlTeUUoFTUNYp09LBx8EAITMnNKSzAbOwdnVFc3AIBBAOTI6nCAgCEx-wmpgGE5hJpwieTg9My5ChzuETgGBmQldHRyimr1E5k+5ABZOAAHAB4mFhbwgbB35kIAHwAzQ7Mx5D5WBBgdBQTTPKwAIxEwAQyDgUCgcAAnuIGgZmgQ3GlwvCkSi0RjscU8U1CES2sguGYYOcQZdzIYGJ50ZicZ4WVAAKKIXCaW4AtHUajDEQiTS7DqUHiYeGQACSMGGCIYEHAmk5nmuGnCAAMACTELk0Dgm8JsqQS+4-EFGUIKxWFUQSTwKXDKVQ3MVGd2UIygxUGnlU-kw4UIUXiyXS2Xyj1grCqiAarU6vUGo0MU0Wq3UG12kwO+xOFxgF1utOUIRe4o+yoFuoMYMesNZSj7UgwKwgKHAXjIZWZ7Pa3W-ADS4QAasDMC96E83vPkEvwgBrCBY+iblfPZ6EJRDke8eiaPcH5CzisShdGegL9kiHDIABucBEZWPngEK4t7hhQwAwMg+pYs8EDoBBP5-lISGBEO1AQDAoAQNQARtCGFAIf+Lyni057DsIvA3vuoHmABOq1re4QIdRTKdNYtjfr+7BcAOF7kXYcBSjKIivEuYp6DgIkAuEvrQPQaqQJiSIQJJuHMjCkHggUFxwcgMlQCYXICdQmjoDs3GacgEF3NWZzoO4xBUHQgTaGMHDhA5ND0AEWKucSyBuB5Tnea57mOV5ABevk7DAMZ2Ts3C8Aw6Afp4IjoAQmjDJSWL8lAWCaDFBaeDOLAQFoYaeMemjuDujEZNIEo7psXnJFlvK5flX6eAhVhlS6ngAFboKAmhhDhRiDcNICjQAOiA42sEAA)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz for your detailed answer. I have one problem with this solution , is that if there are maps with similar keys , it leaves just one , not both of them , I need them to be both added in my result.

Comment: it means that I don't need the computeIfAbsent() method ?

Comment: What do you mean by "maps with similar keys"?  In your example code there is only one map, named `Fields`.   What do you mean by "both added in my result"?  The code I present merges `Set`s into new `Sets`.  If you want to "add" them in some other way, let me know.  Ideally you should provide a [mcve] that shows exactly what you expect the inputs and outputs to be.  Please read the description of what constitutes a [mcve].  Good luck!

Comment: thank you , I mis-explained in my comment , your code work perfectly  fine.